# Is there any need to specify PRAGMA page_size = 4096 for a new mobile phone application with SQLite?

Tags: sqlite

For a Xamarin Mobile phone application, can someone explain what these three statements do and if they are really needed when creating a SQLite database:

```
    db.execute("PRAGMA page_size = 4096");
    db.execute("PRAGMA legacy_file_format = 0");
    db.execute("VACUUM");
```

Answer (score 0):

The default page size has been 4k since [version 3.12.0 from March 2016](https://www.sqlite.org/pgszchng2016.html), so unless you're using an older version or a version compiled with a custom default page size (or a database originally created with such a version), there's no reason to set the size to 4k.

The  [`legacy_file_format`](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_legacy_file_format) pragma is a no-op that does nothing. I don't know when this changed. The legacy file format is needed to create a database that can be read by versions before 3.3.0. It has defaulted to off since [3.7.10 from January 2012](https://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#default_file_format) but can still be enabled (or disabled on an existing legacy DB) via the [C dbconfig API](https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_dbconfig_defensive.html#sqlitedbconfiglegacyfileformat).

The `VACUUM` is needed on a populated database to make a page size change actually take effect.

So, to summarize: unless you're using really old outdated SQLite versions or non-standard compile time defaults, no, you don't need any of that.